# Rails 5 beta Turbolinks events not firing, progress bar not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks, beta

I'm kind of new to Rails and web development as a whole.
I'm trying to set up the default progress bar in Turbolinks for rails just like described [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#displaying-progress).

At first, I thought it might have to do with the fact that the progress bar only shows if a page takes longer than 500ms to load. I tried testing this using `sleep 10` in my controller but it doesn't seem to work.

Then I tried debugging the actual turbolink events to see if the callbacks are registering using vanilla js straight in my `application.js`:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
    console.log("load");
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", function () {
    console.log("request start");
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:visit", function () {
    console.log("visit");
});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:render", function () {
    console.log("render");
});
```

For some reason, only the `turbolinks:load` function seems to work.

What am I not seeing or doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes. I tried using `.turbolinks-progress-bar` with a height of 5px and green color.

Comment: Any update to this? I am experiencing the same issue.